# Calculating the number of active employees as at previous months with DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

I am wondering if there's a way to calculate the number of active employees with the use of start date/ termination date without having to create a daily snapshot table.

the employee table is like this:

```
Emp_ID.   Start Date        Termination Date      other columns
```

and obviously Dim_date is as usual:

```
Date_key      Date            Year.    Month.    Etc...
```

Employee table is connected to Dim_Date via Start Date field, so if we use a DAX formula like :

```
ActiveEmps =
CALCULATE (
COUNTX (
    FILTER (
        employee,
        [start date] < MIN ( Dim_Date[Date] )
            && [Termination Date] > MAX ( Dim_Date[Date] )
    ),
    Emp_ID
) 
,other filters within calculate context)
```

It won't work and the reason is it's only counting active employees in which their start date falls within the selected time period. (because of the relationship)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have done it this way:

```
ActiveEmps :=
VAR ThisDate =
    MIN( Dim_Date[Date] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS( employee ),
        FILTER(
            ALL( employee ),
            employee[Start Date] < ThisDate
                && employee[Termination Date] > ThisDate
        )
    )
```

Comment: That's great Jos, any idea how to calculate the last rolling 12 months average?

Comment: adding Datesinperiod(Date[Date],max(date[date]),-12,month) won't work I'm afraid because of the relationship